# How to add text to an active UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a couple of `UITextField`'s and one `UIButton`. If I tap on the `UIButton`, I want to place some static text in the active `UITextField`.

So something like:

```
@IBAction func buttonEen(sender: UIButton) {
    'active textField'.text = "static text"
}
```

But how do I determine which `UITextField` is the active `UITextField` and how do I reach it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write text in last active UITextField you have to make your `UIViewController` a delegate of `UITextField`

ex:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

declare a `activeField` variable

ex:

```
var activeField: UITextField?
```

then implements `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

ex:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField)
{
    activeField = textField
}
```

So your button function will be something like

```
@IBAction func buttonEen(sender: UIButton) {
if activeField
    {
        activeField.text = "static text"
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'v tried that, Nerkyator. I already use textFieldDidEndEditing for other fields to make sure I get the input I want. Guess that influences your solution... I don't get the expected result. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create your textfield delegate (probably in 'ViewDidLoad()') :

```
activeTxtField.delegate = self
```

Then you need to implement the textField delegate function:

```
extension 'YourVC': UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == activeTxtField {
        // Do whatever you want
        // e.g set textField text to "static text"
     }
  }
}
```