# How can I append text to the active UITextField - Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make a custom keyboard. But I cannot input info on the active textField. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

PS: The keyboard is in another ViewController and is passing the sender.tag well.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController, ButtonTapDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var keyboardView: UIView!

var activeField: UITextField?
var delegate: ButtonTapDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    addKeyboard(view: keyboardView)
    textField1.inputView = UIView()
    textField2.inputView = UIView()
    textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
    activeField?.delegate = self
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    activeField = textField
}
func addKeyboard(view: UIView) {
    let keyboard = KeyboardVC(nibName: "KeyboardVC", bundle: nil)
    keyboard.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(keyboard.view)
    addChild(keyboard)
}

func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 8 {
        activeField?.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")
    } else if sender.tag == 9 {
        activeField?.text?.removeAll()
    } else {
        let val = sender.titleLabel?.text
        activeField?.text?.append(contentsOf: val!)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You need to assign the text back to the field, modifying the text inline doesn't modify the version held by the textfield itself.  `activeField?.text = activeField?.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")` or something similar

Comment: That logic might seem right, but doesn't work. If I change 'activeField?.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")' for 'textField1.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")' it works fine, but just for the textField1. I need it for the active textField.

Comment: The your `activeField` is likely `nil`

Comment: Did you set breakpoints in `didTapButton()` in order to ensure that `activeField?.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")` is getting called?

Comment: Is there an error or does it just not append text?

Comment: Yes. As a matter of fact, I printed all tags and they work fine. Also, if I change the activeField for textField1 or textField2, it works. But what I want to do is to select an active UITextField add text to it.

Comment: There is no error. It just doesn't append anything.

Comment: Does `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` get called before `didTapButton()`?

Comment: @Nerkyator can you help? This looks familiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400367/how-to-add-text-to-an-active-uitextfield

Comment: @Xcoder 'didTapButton()' is getting called before 'textFieldDidBeginEditing()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it after some research with changes to the **textFieldDidBeginEditing** and **didTapButton** functions: Here is the full code if anybody wants to choose one textField at a time with a custom keyboard:

---

```
import UIKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController, ButtonTapDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var textField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var textField2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var keyboardView: UIView!

var activeField: UITextField?
var delegate: ButtonTapDelegate!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    addKeyboard(view: keyboardView)
    textField1.inputView = UIView()
    textField2.inputView = UIView()
    textField1.becomeFirstResponder()
    activeField?.delegate = self
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
   self.activeField = textField
}

func addKeyboard(view: UIView) {
    let keyboard = KeyboardVC(nibName: "KeyboardVC", bundle: nil)
    keyboard.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(keyboard.view)
    addChild(keyboard)
}

func didTapButton(sender: UIButton) {
        if textField1 == self.activeField {
            if sender.tag == 8 {
                textField1.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")
            } else if sender.tag == 9 {
                textField1.text?.removeAll()
            } else {
                let val = sender.titleLabel?.text?
                textField1.text?.append(contentsOf: val!)
            }
            return;
        }

    if textField2 == self.activeField {
        if sender.tag == 8 {
            textField2.text?.append(contentsOf: " ")
        } else if sender.tag == 9 {
            textField2.text?.removeAll()
        } else {
            let val = sender.titleLabel?.text?
            textField2.text?.append(contentsOf: val!)
        }
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight problem in your code that is causing your issue. In the comments, you mentioned that `didTapButton()` is called **before**`textFieldDidBeginEditing`. This means that `actionField` is not assigned a value and therefore is nil. Your code in `didTapButton()` safely unwraps the optional value so that no error is produced, but of course, you cannot append text to a non-existent `UITextField`.

Comment: Thank for the tip, but this doesn't answer the question above.

Comment: @JoseFermin No problem. What “question” isn’t answered? I’d be happy to help.

Comment: The question I'm referring to is: 
How can I append text to the active UITextField - Swift. In any case, I was able to fix it. My answer is below.