# Using UIButtons to input into UITextFields all in a custom keyboard, keyboard reappears, not inputting text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to make a custom iOS keyboard, all contained in the `BibleKeyboardView.swift` and `BibleKeyboardView.xib` file. Part of the view contains multiple UITextFields which I want to be inputted by the number buttons. However, when I click on any of the UITextFields, the keyboard closes and then reappear, the cursor never stays in the UITextField, and the UIButtons don't do anything.

[Gif of the keyboard disappearing/reappearing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZCur.gif)

I've tried setting each of the UITextField's `inputView = self` but that only kept the keyboard closed. I have also set each number button as a keyboard key in the storyboard right side menu.

This is my code, but when I try running it, `activeField` is nil and throws an `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` error. The code never makes it to `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` because that print statement doesn't run (based on [How to add text to an active UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400367/how-to-add-text-to-an-active-uitextfield)).

[activeField is nil error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5lFh.png)

```
class BibleKeyboardView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var chapterA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verseA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var chapterB: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verseB: UITextField!

    var activeField: UITextField?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        activeField?.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = textField
        activeField?.inputView = self
        print("made active field")
    }

    @IBAction func numBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        activeField!.text = activeField!.text! + (sender.titleLabel?.text!)!
}
```

The dream is that I can input numbers into each UITextField when tapping on using the numeric pad that I coded. **Why does the keyboard keep disappearing and reappearing when I click on the UITextField? Why is textFieldDidBeginEditing not running?**

Comment: Have you set delegate for each `UITextField`?

Comment: It looks like you are setting the delegate for activeField before assigning it to anything. Try assigning it each time textFieldDidBeginEditing or set for each of your 4 textFields in viewdidLoad.

Comment: @Magnas Setting the delegate for each text field in awakeFromNib() and removing activeField?.inputView = self from textFieldDidBeginEditing allowed me to input into the text field. Thanks! Keyboard still closes and reappears.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni when I tried it, it makes it to textFieldDidBeginEditing function but the keyboard still closes and reappears. Nevertheless, at least now I can input into my text fields. Thanks!

Comment: can you share any demo project where I can check this problem? @AmyFang

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Hi Dharmesh, I sent it to your email. I also found out that when I run on an actual iPad (vs a simulator which I had been doing), clicking on the text fields changes it back to the regular keyboard :/ Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the end: setting the delegate and inputView for each `UITextField` within `awakeFromNib()`. Also, it seems the keyboard closing/reappearing issue only happens on the iPad simulator, but when I run it on an actual iPad, it goes away.

```
class BibleKeyboardView: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var chapterA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verseA: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var chapterB: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var verseB: UITextField!

   var activeField: UITextField?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        chapterA.delegate = self
        chapterA.inputView = self

        verseA.delegate = self
        verseA.inputView = self

        chapterB.delegate = self
        chapterB.inputView = self

        verseB.delegate = self
        verseB.inputView = self
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        activeField = textField
    }

    @IBAction func numBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        activeField!.text = activeField!.text! + (sender.titleLabel?.text!)!
    }
}
```